# Why would I need a module manifest - because the module nesting limit has been exceeded

Tags: powershell, module, manifest, powershell-module

I just got an error in Powershell:

```
 because the module nesting limit has been exceeded. Modules can only be nested to 10 levels.
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29852245/what-is-the-module-nesting-limit-in-powershell) and found something called a "module manifest". I already have a module .psm1 files - why do I also need this?

Note: I dont have 10 levels of modules, I have 10 modules, all loaded in by one import.psm1 file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **module nesting level getting exceeded is typically the result of accidentally getting into an *infinite recursion during module import*** (irrespective of whether you import via [`Import-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module) or the PSv5+ `using module` statement).

This **can happen whether or not your module has a manifest**; the answer to the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29852245/what-is-the-module-nesting-limit-in-powershell) shows how it can happen *with* a manifest; here's an example *without* one: the following  `foo.psm1` module causes an infinite recursion that results in the error message you saw

```bsh
# Create sample module (without manifest).
@'
# Accidentally try to import the module itself.
using module .\foo.psm1

function bar { 'hi from module foo' }
'@ > foo.psm1

# This fails, because an infinite import loop is entered, 
# eventually causing the nesting limit to be exceeded.
Import-Module .\foo.psm1
```

---

#### Why creating a (script) module *with a manifest* is a good idea:

While **module manifests are *optional*** - standalone `*.psm1` files can serve as [modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules) by themselves - there are **good reasons to use them**:

**A module manifest is a `*.psd1` file that accompanies your `*.psm1` file and specifies important *metadata***, notably the version number, in the form of a *hashtable literal*; for the best user experience, **both files should be placed in a *directory* of the *same name*** (e.g., `Foo.psm1` and its manifest, `Foo.psd1`, should be placed in a directory named `Foo`).

By using a manifested module, you **enable several important use cases**:

- You need a manifest to properly support your module's software-development processes, notably version management.

  - It is also a prerequisite for supporting *side-by-side* installations of multiple versions of your module.
- You need a manifest to automatically load associated resources, such as other modules or auxiliary .NET assemblies, and to define help resources.
- You need a manifest in order to integrate with PowerShell's [module auto-loading mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules#module-auto-loading): If you place your properly manifested module into one of the directories listed in `$env:PSModulePath`, PowerShell will:

  - Discover the module and its commands even before the module is imported.
  - Will import it *on demand*, the first time you try to call a command from the session.
- You need a manifest in order to publish a module to the official online repository for PowerShell modules, the [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/)

---

To quickly outline the **steps for creating a module with manifest**:

- Create a *directory* named for the base name of your `.psm1` file; e.g., `Foo`
- Place the script code as file `Foo.psm1` file in that directory.
- In the same directory, using the [`New-ModuleManifest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-modulemanifest) cmdlet, create the manifest `.psd1` file with the same base name (e.g., `Foo.psd1`)
- At the very least, update the `RootModule` entry in the new `.psd1` file to point to your `.psm1` file (e.g., `RootModule = 'Foo.psm1'`)
- To integrate with the auto-loading feature, place your module directory in one of the locations listed in `$env:PSModulePath`; for the current user, that location is:

  - Windows PowerShell:

    - `$HOME\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`
  - PowerShell [Core] v6+:

    - Windows: `$HOME\Documents\PowerShell\Modules`
    - Linux, macOS: `$HOME/.local/share/powershell/Modules`
- To support module discovery and auto-loading *efficiently* and to *explicitly control and signal what a module exports*, it is best to *explicitly list* the individual exported module members in the `FunctionsToExport`, 
  `CmdletsToExport`, `VariablesToExport`, and `AliasesToExport` entries of the manifest.

---

To **make module creation easier**, the community has provided **helper modules**:

- [`Plaster`](https://github.com/PowerShell/Plaster) is a "template-based file and project generator written in PowerShell", that can also be used to scaffold modules:

  - The built-in "New PowerShell Manifest Module" template scaffolds a module directory with all necessary files and support for [`Pester`](https://github.com/Pester/Pester) tests.
  - See [this blog post](https://overpoweredshell.com/Working-with-Plaster/) for a walk-through.
- [`Stucco`](https://github.com/devblackops/stucco) builds on Plaster to provide an "opinionated Plaster template for building high-quality PowerShell modules."

  - Stucco is an advanced tool that goes beyond mere module creation, by scaffolding an entire project structure that includes [`psake`](https://github.com/psake/psake) tasks, scaffolding for  CI/CD integration, licensing, and help authoring.

---

A quick example with `Plaster`:

```
# Install Plaster for the current user, if necessary.
Install-Module Plaster -Scope CurrentUser

# Get the template for creating a new script module.
$template = Get-PlasterTemplate | Where TemplatePath -match ScriptModule

# Scaffold a module in subdirectory 'Foo'
#  * This will present a series of prompts, most of them with default values.
#  * IMPORTANT: Be sure to also choose 'Foo' as the module *name* when prompted,
#               so that the module auto-loading feature can discover your module
#               (if placed in a dir. in $env:PSModulePath) and also so that you 
#               you can load it by its *directory* path; e.g., Import-Module ./Foo
Invoke-Plaster -TemplatePath $template.TemplatePath -Destination Foo

# Add a test function to the `.psm1` file.
# Note: 
#  * This is just for illustrative purposes. In real life, you would
#    obviously use an editor to add functions to your module.
#  * The function must be placed *before* the `Export-ModuleMember` call in order
#    to be exported.
#  * As stated, it is additionally recommended to list the exported members
#    *explicitly*, one by one, in the *ToExport keys of the *.psd1 file.
(Get-Content -Raw ./Foo/Foo.psm1) -replace '\r?\n\r?\n', "`n`nfunction Get-Foo { 'Hi from module Foo.' }`n" | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 ./Foo/Foo.psm1

# Import the newly created module by its *directory* path.
# IMPORTANT: 
#   As stated, this assumes that you specified 'Foo' as the module name, i.e.
#   that your manifest's file name is 'Foo.psd1', and your script module's
#   'Foo.psm1'.
Import-Module ./Foo -Verbose -Force

'---'

# Call the test function
Get-Foo

'---'

# Invoke the module's tests.
# Note: The scaffolding creates a single test to ensure that the
#       module manifest (*.psd1) is valid.
Invoke-Pester ./Foo
```

You should see output such as the following:

```
VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'C:\Users\jdoe\Foo\Foo.psd1'.
VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'C:\Users\jdoe\Foo\Foo.psm1'.
VERBOSE: Importing function 'Get-Foo'.
---
Hi from module Foo.
---
    ____            __
   / __ \___  _____/ /____  _____
  / /_/ / _ \/ ___/ __/ _ \/ ___/
 / ____/  __(__  ) /_/  __/ /
/_/    \___/____/\__/\___/_/
Pester v4.9.0
Executing all tests in './Foo'

Executing script C:\Users\jdoe\Foo\test\Foo.Tests.ps1

  Describing Module Manifest Tests
    [+] Passes Test-ModuleManifest 128ms
Tests completed in 375ms
Tests Passed: 1, Failed: 0, Skipped: 0, Pending: 0, Inconclusive: 0
```