# Why are -ErrorAction Stop / $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop' sometimes ineffective, e.g. with implicit remoting / Windows PowerShell Compatibility?

Tags: powershell, error-handling, powershell-remoting, powershell-core

This self-answered question, written as of PowerShell (Core) v7.3.x, aims to address the following symptoms:

Sometimes, neither using [`-ErrorAction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-erroraction) `-Stop` nor [`$ErrorActionPreference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#erroractionpreference) `= 'Stop'` appears to be effective for being able to catch and handle an error via a [`try` / `catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally) statement.

Here are two examples :

- `Get-NetAdapter` ignores `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` *from a script or function* (from a [scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Scopes) other than the *global* one):

  ```bash
  # Run on Windows. Affects both PowerShell editions.
  # The `catch` block isn't triggered, and the (still non-terminating) error prints.
  & { # Simulate running in a child scope.
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
    try {     
      Get-NetAdapter nosuch 
    }
    catch {
      "Should get here, but don't."
    }
  }
  ```

  - However, use of `-ErrorAction Stop` (`Get-NetAdapter nosuch -ErrorAction Stop`) *does* work as expected.
- **[This turned out to be a bug in *preview versions of PowerShell (Core) v7.4 only*]** `Get-AppLockerFileInformation` ignores *both* a non-global `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` *and* use of `ErrorAction Stop`; only the latter is shown here:

  ```bash
  # Run on Windows. Affects PowerShell (Core) v7+ only
  # The `catch` block isn't triggered, and the (still non-terminating) error prints.
  try {
    Get-AppLockerFileInformation NoSuch.exe -ErrorAction Stop
  }
  catch {
    "Should get here, but don't in PowerShell (Core)."
  }
  ```

  - See [GitHub issue #20209](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20209)

So the questions are:

- What determines when `-ErrorAction` and/or `$ErrorActionPreference` are ineffective?
- What workarounds are available when they aren't?

Comment: One of the reasons why for me it does not make sense to use Powershell modules in my daily business. A script should be reliable and function on its own. Workarounds such as described here just complicate things for little benefit https://github.com/sdoubleday/GetCallerPreference/blob/master/GetCallerPreference.psm1

Comment: @DavidTrevor, (manifested) modules are essential for proper packaging and version management of PowerShell code (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59935572/45375) for a discussion), but I empathize with the frustration that arises from having to deal with the the historical warts and design flaws.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two related factors determine whether `-ErrorAction` and/or `$ErrorActionPreference` are ineffective when calling a given command:

- Fundamentally, due to how PowerShell's scoping works, commands hosted in a *script* module (i.e. one implemented in PowerShell, as opposed to via a compiled .NET assembly) do *not* see the caller's [preference variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables), including `$ErrorActionPreference`, except when calling from the *global* scope, which is *not* the case when you call from a (non-dot-sourced) script or function.

  - This - very unfortunate - design limitation is the subject of [GitHub issue #4568](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4568). Said issue also mentions the [`PreferenceVariables`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PreferenceVariables) module, which script-module *authors* can use to work around the limitation (see [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/weekend-scripter-access-powershell-preference-variables/) for details).
  - For *callers*, using `-ErrorAction Stop`, i.e. the corresponding [*common parameter*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-erroraction), on a *per-call basis*, *is* honored, but *isn't fully equivalent*, because it doesn't also apply to *statement*-terminating errors and therefore additionally explicitly requires converting the latter to *script*-terminating (fatal) ones using `try` / `catch` with `throw` or an equivalent `trap` statement - see below for details and an alternative workaround via (temporarily) setting `$ErrorActionPreference` *globally*.
- Modules that use [implicit remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-pssession) - which are by definition *script* modules too - may introduce an *additional* complication:

  - **IMPORTANT**: **The following either *no longer applies* to Windows PowerShell 5.1 / PowerShell (Core) 7+ or may only affect select modules** - I don't know which; I have old notes suggesting that implicitly remoting Exchange cmdlets were affected in Windows PowerShell *5*; do tell us if you have more information.
  - With commands from such modules, even `-ErrorAction Stop` is *categorically* ineffective, because this parameter is *propagated* to the *remotely executing* command, and - by design - *remotely* occurring terminating errors translate *locally* into *non-terminating* errors.

    - I believe the design rationale behind this to be the following, related to PowerShell [remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Remote) in general:

      - When targeting *multiple* remote machines, such as via [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command)'s `-ComputerName` parameter, a *terminating* error occurring *remotely* should not terminate the multi-machine operation *overall*, therefore such *remotely* terminating errors are translated into *locally* non-terminating ones.
      - **[NO LONGER TRUE IN GENERAL]** This logic applies to scenarios with *implicit remoting* too - despite the fact that by definition only *one* remote machine is being targeted.
  - While using implicit remoting *usually* requires explicit action - such as the use of the [`Import-PSSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-pssession) cmdlet - there is one scenario where implicit remoting is *automatically* used by default:

    - In [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), if you try to use commands from a module that is compatible with *Windows PowerShell only*, the associated module is by default automatically imported via the [Windows PowerShell Compatibility feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Windows_PowerShell_Compatibility), which involves communicating via a *hidden `powershell.exe` child process*.
    - While this isn't technically *remoting*, given that everything happens on the local machine, the underlying *cross-process* communication mechanism is the same as in true remoting, which - as an aside - also reduces *type fidelity* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180367/45375).
    - The only way to turn such remotely occurring, invariably *non-terminating* errors into *terminating* ones that can be caught with `try` / `catch` is to (temporarily) set the *global* incarnation of the `$ErrorActionPreference` variable to `'Stop'`, as shown below.

---

**Workarounds**:

- *Either*: **On a *per-call basis*, use `-ErrorAction Stop`** rather than `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`, for full robustness in combination with either [`try` / `catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally) or [`trap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Trap) to ensure that (the relatively rare) *statement*-terminating errors too are converted to *script*-terminating (fatal) ones:

  ```bash
    try {     
      Get-NetAdapter nosuch -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch {
      Write-Verbose -Verbose "OK, caught: $_"
      # If desired, re-throw to make script-terminating (fatal)
      throw 
    }

    # ------------------------
    # ALTERNATIVE, via `trap`:

    trap { 
      Write-Verbose -Verbose "OK, caught: $_"
      # If desired, use `break` to ensure that the error is script-terminating (fatal).
      # Use `continue` to quietly continue.
      break 
    }

    Get-NetAdapter nosuch -ErrorAction Stop
  ```

  - **Note**:

    - Unfortunately, `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` and `-ErrorAction Stop` aren't created equal: the latter only acts on *non-terminating* errors, whereas the former acts on *statement-terminating* errors too - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72802148/45375). However, in the context of using `try` / `catch` and `trap`, this distinction doesn't matter, because a statement-terminating error by itself also triggers the `catch` block / `trap` script block.
    - *If* there is still a problem with modules that use *[implicit remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-pssession)*, you'll need the next workaround instead.
- *Or*: **Temporarily set `$global:ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`**, i.e. set the preference variable *globally*.

  ```bash
    & { # Simulate running in a child scope.
      $prevGlobalPref = $global:ErrorActionPreference
      $global:ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
      try {     
        Get-AppLockerFileInformation NoSuch.exe
      }
      catch {
        Write-Verbose -Verbose "OK, caught: $_"
        # If desired, re-throw to make script-terminating (fatal)
        throw 
      } finally {
        $global:ErrorActionPreference = $prevGlobalPref
      }
    }
  ```

---

As for **how to tell whether a given command is from either module type (*regular* vs. *implicitly remoting*)**:

- The following **helper function, `Get-CommandModuleType`**, tells you what type of module a given command is from, with output `'Script'` indicating a regular (non-implicitly-remoting) script module, and `'ImplicitRemoting'` an implicitly remoting one; see the comment-based help in the source code for details.
- Sample calls, from PowerShell (Core) on Windows:

  ```bash
  # -> 'Script'  
  Get-CommandModuleType Get-NetAdapter 

  # -> 'ImplicitRemoting'
  Get-CommandModuleType Get-AppLockerFileInformation
  ```

```bash
function Get-CommandModuleType {
  <#
  .SYNOPSIS
    Indicates a given command's module type.
  .DESCRIPTION
    Aliases are automatically resolved to their underlying commands.
  
    Note:
     * The output is a *string* that is one of the following:    
       * '(None)', If the command is a function *not from a module*.
       * 'ImplicitRemoting' for an implicitly remoting module.
       * 'Script' for regular script modules (that don't use implicit remoting)
       * 'Binary' if the command is a *binary cmdlet* - even if its part of
         a module that is a *script* module, due to *also* containing 
         PowerShell code. Strictly speaking, binary cmdlets are themselves
         modules.
     * Not all script modules report themselves as such via the underlying
       module's manifest; some of them report just 'Manifest'. Conversely,
       a script module can also contain *binary* cmdlets.
       To see the actual value from the module definition, use the -Raw switch.
    
  .EXAMPLE
    Get-CommandModuleType Get-NetAdapter
  
    Reports the *de facto* type of the Get-NetAdapter command.

  .EXAMPLE
    Get-CommandModuleType Get-NetAdapter -Raw 
  
    Reports the *formal* type of the module that hosts the Get-NetAdapter, as
    specified in its manifest.
  #>
  
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $CommandName,
        [switch] $Raw
    )
  
    $command = Get-Command $CommandName
    if ($command -and $command.ResolvedCommand) { 
        $command = $command.ResolvedCommand
        Write-Verbose "Resolved command is: $command"
    }
    if ($module = $command.Module) {
        Write-Verbose "Source module is: $module; command type is $($command.CommandType)"
        if (-not $Raw -and $command.CommandType -in 'Function', 'Filter') {
            # A function from a script module
            if ($module.PrivateData.ImplicitRemoting) {
                # an implicitly remoting module
                'ImplicitRemoting'
            }
            else {
                'Script'
            }
        }
        elseif (-not $Raw -and $command.CommandType -eq 'Cmdlet') {
            'Binary'
        }
        else {
            if ($Raw) { Write-Verbose 'Reporting raw module type, i.e as manifested.' }
            $module.ModuleType.ToString()
        }
    }
    else {
        '(None)'  
    }
}
```