# Why is `Install-Module` not respecting $ErrorActionPreference=Stop from the script scope?

Tags: powershell, powershell-core, powershell-7.0

I have the following script:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
Install-Module 'DoesNotExist' -Force
Write-Host "This should not be printed!"
```

I'd assumed, that if an error occurs in `Install-Module`, it terminates, because I set `$ErrorActionPreference` to `Stop`. Unfortunately it doesn't.

What even makes it weirder is, that if I set `$ErrorActionPreference` in the `global` scope to `Stop`, it works.

```
$global:ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're seeing an unfortunate **design limitation**, discussed in [GitHub issue #4568](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4568):

**Problem**:

Commands implemented *as PowerShell [functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions)* that *originate in [modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules)*:

- do *not* see any [preference variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables) set in the caller's [scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Scopes)...
- ... *except* if the calling scope happens to be the *global* one - which is typically *not* the case.

Unfortunately, there are no good solutions to this problem, only cumbersome workarounds:

**Workaround for *callers***:

A non-global caller, such as a script or a function (which run in a *child* scope by default) must:

- *Either*: Explicitly set preference variables in the *global* scope (e.g., `$global:ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`)

  - So as not to affect subsequently executing code, be sure to *restore their original values* afterwards, which - for robustness - must be done in the `finally` clause of a [`try` / `catch` / `finally`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally) statement.
- *Or*: On a *call-by-call* basis, use the corresponding [common parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters) (e.g. `-ErrorAction Stop`)

  - The challenge with `-ErrorAction Stop` is that it is *not* fully equivalent to `$global:ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` in that only acts on *non-terminating* errors, and not also on *statement*-terminating ones, additionally necessitating a `try` / `catch` or a [`trap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Trap) statement. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60549569/45375) for background information.

These workarounds are spelled out in detail in the middle section of [this closely related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77056311/45375).

Generally, the challenge is to know *when a workaround is even needed*, as a given command's name doesn't reveal whether it is PowerShell-implemented and whether it comes from a module.
You can use the following test for a given command; if it returns `$true`, the workaround is needed:

```bash
# -> $true, 
# because Install-Module is from a module and implemented as a PowerShell function.
& {
  $cmd = Get-Command $args[0] 
  $cmd.CommandType -eq 'Function' -and $cmd.ModuleName 
} Install-Module
```

**Workaround for *module authors***:

Dave Wyatt has authored a *helper module*, [`PreferenceVariables`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PreferenceVariables), whose `Get-CallerPreference` function can be used inside module functions to obtain an outside caller's preference variables.

In other words: You can use this to overcome the design limitation and make your PowerShell-implemented cmdlet ([advanced function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced)) behave like *binary* cmdlets with respect to the caller's preference variables.<sup>[1]</sup>

`Get-CallerPreference` use is explained in [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/weekend-scripter-access-powershell-preference-variables/).

Note: You don't strictly need another *module* to implement this functionality, it - which doesn't require much code - could be integrated directly into a module.

---

<sup>[1] There are other, subtle differences, discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51912471/45375).</sup>